# Regex to match quotes like q'[Mike's bike]'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will match [Oracle q-quotes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm) for a PL/SQL lexer in [code-prettify.js](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). For example,

```
q'[Here's Johnny]'
```

This should be matched the same as

```
'Here''s Johnny'
```

(that is, so that SQL will treat it all as one text string. The advantage of q-quotes over the conventional two-single-quotes is you don't have to go through your text string doubling up all of your single quotes.)

The quote delimiter can be any of [, {, <, or (, but I think if I can get it working with one bracket type then I can repeat the variations as ORs, like

```
/^(?:pattern1|pattern2|pattern3))/
```

Ultimately I want a single regex that will match an ordinary single-quoted string or a q-quote with any of the bracket types.

Comment: It should match to `'Here''s Johnny'` ? That's a double ' or a single " ?

Comment: @Onilol - either, but I meant two single quotes. That's the standard way of quoting a quote in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your lexer you would like the text of `q'[Here's Johnny]'` and `'Here''s Johnny'` to be matched. Assuming that you want the match to include all characters comprising the string token, including quotes, brackets, etc, this regular expression should work:

`(?:q'\[.*?\](?=')'|q'<.*?>(?=')'|q'\(.*?\)(?=')'|q'{.*?}(?=')'|(?!q)'(?:[^']|'')*')`

The two relevant pieces are:

1. `q'\[.*?\](?=')'` is the basis for q-quoted strings, and the rest of the appropriate brackets have their own statements, and
2. `'(?:[^']|'')*'`, matches single-quoted strings.

You can see matching examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/lD2dY5/4).

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Working example at http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/test_plsql_highlighting.html (deleted and re-added this comment a couple of times as I thought I still had a problem with prettify.js, but fixed it now.)